# Memory consumption by using setFetchSize()

Tags: java, jdbc

```
setFetchSize()
```

Lets say that fetch size is 1000, when result set has 1000 rows in memory buffer, `rs.next()` will fetch from memory buffer.
After 1000 rows, it will make a DB trip and fetch next 1000 rows. 
My question is : will the memory of previously fetched 1000 rows in ResultSet get released by JVM ?

Comment: There is nothing special about JBDC. If there is a reference to the result set, neither it nor its children will be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Java memory allocation and release is done by GC thread. `setFetchSize()` not involved the memory allocation/release. When your application has huge memory , GC will not happen when you use `setFetchSize()` & `rs.next()`. If there is no memory for allocating new Objects ,then GC happens.

Comment: so coming back to my  question, Will result set hold references to earlier fetched rows from DB ?

Comment: This is not generally answerable as it depends on the JDBC driver implementation.